# Custom category and tag page header title in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

for better SEO I need change product category and tags header title. For example I have category "Unicorn" and I need add text "Free svg files". Its too long and will be confusing if it will be in categories listing and on product page in this format. For this reason I need show Unicorn free svg files only on category product page and in categories listing and on product page keep category named only as "Unicorn".

I have this code which works exactly as I need

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'customize_woocommerce_page_title', 10, 1 );
function customize_woocommerce_page_title( $page_title) {

    if ( is_product_category('unicorn') ) {
        $page_title = 'Unicorn Free SVG Files';
    }
    elseif ( is_product_category('lips') ) {
        $page_title = 'Lips Free SVG Files';
    }
    return $page_title;
}
```

But problem is that I have over 100 categories and hundreds tags and it will be complicated if added manually. I simply need add text "Free SVG Files" to every category and tag page. Except for few category and tag pages.

Thank you for any advice.